# How to export automatically the content of an assistant in the new user experience of Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

In the **new user experience** you can download content of an assistant manually in JSON format. However, I need to do it automatically.

I'm able to export/download the content of a workspace by using get_workspace method with export=True by using V1 of the API. However, in the new user experience where I built an action skills based chat bot, I can't get the workspace id which is required for this method.
Is there other option or some workaround to download the assistant's content in the **new user experience**?

Comment: The API for this is not released yet.

Comment: Thank you @SimonO'Doherty! Do you know roughly when to expect to be released.

Comment: I don't have any official statement. I would recommend to keep an eye on the release notes as they add features frequently. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-watson-assistant-release-notes

Answer (score 1):

You can now import/export skills now in the new user experience using these APIs:

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2#exportskills
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2#importskills

Note that these are not currently supported in the SDKs but they should get picked up in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian mentioned the API is available now, but the documentation isn't up to date. There will also be further updates which will likely make easier (again no official date).

At the moment the export only exports the "Draft".

#### Sample: Export skill

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import json

username = 'apikey'
password = '<API_KEY>'

service_instance = '<SERVICE_URL>'

assistant_id = '<ASSISTANT_ID>'
version = '2021-11-27'

url = f'{service_instance}/v2/assistants/{assistant_id}/skills_export?version={version}'

max_tries = 3
skill = None
while max_tries > 0:
    data = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password)).json()

    if 'assistant_skills' in data:
        skill = data['assistant_skills'][0]
        break
    if 'error' in data:
        print(data)
        break

    sleep(5)
    print(f'Retrying {max_tries}...')
    max_tries = max_tries - 1

if skill is not None:
    filename = f"{skill['name'].replace(' ', '-')}-action.json"
    print(f"Skill downloaded: {filename}")

    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(skill, indent=2))
```

The related fields can be gotten from the environment settings (click cog on Draft).

[image: Picture of UI showing were the data can be found to fill out code.]